# Error fetching interface information: Device not found

Tags: networking, vmware, ethernet

Running 14.04 on VMWare player, I am trying to configure a new Ethernet device `eth1` through editing `/etc/network/interfaces`.

I have configured a device for `eth0`, and that is working properly.

Here is my `interfaces` file:

[image: interfaces configuration]

And the output from `ifconfig -a`:

[image: ifconfig output]

I have tried `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart` and `sudo service networking restart`
of which both work, but running `ifconfig eth1` returns

```
eth1: error fetching interface information: Device not found.
```

I have also tried suggestions from other threads such as leaving out some fields such as network from interfaces, to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added a second interface unit in vmware?

https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net_configurations_changing_vadapters.html